# Pass a refrence for thread constructor to bind it to function fails?

Tags: c++, multithreading, binding, arguments, c++14

I have a `void fun(vector<int> & v)` and I want to pass a vector to it when instantiating a thread `thread t(fun, v);`. In [C++14 clang 4](https://ideone.com/S7VYGw) compilation fails, in [MSVC it runs passing a copy](http://rextester.com/GWC48010) to function.

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(vector<int> & v) {
    v.push_back(13);
}

int main(){
    vector<int> v;
    thread t(fun, v);
    t.join();
    cout << v.size();
}
```

example of gcc 5.4.0 error:

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/thread:39:0,
>                    from source_file.cpp:1: /usr/include/c++/5/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct
>   std::_Bind_simple))(std::vector&)>’:
>   /usr/include/c++/5/thread:137:59:   required from
>   ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void
>   (&)(std::vector&); _Args = {std::vector
>
> > &}]’ source_file.cpp:12:21:   required from here /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in
> >     ‘class std::result_of))(std::vector&)>’
> >            typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
> >                                                                  ^ /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in
> >     ‘class std::result_of))(std::vector&)>’
> >              _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)

So 1) what is c++ standard stand on this issue; 2) is there a way around it (not [passing a pointer](https://ideone.com/6bQniq) and not +1 extra [lambda expression as wrapper](https://ideone.com/Knr2jA))?

Comment: I think you may need [std::ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Comment: @Galik: great answer!)) [It works](https://ideone.com/Lzo7sG), but why simple refrence passing does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik) in the comment, all you need is [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
thread t(fun, std::ref(v));
```

**Why ?**

This is because  your function `fun()` expects a reference to an lvalue.  However when you construct your [`thread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), a copy of your arguments will be passed in the new thread.  Unfortunately, the compiler will not be able to instantiate the templates behind the scene with a reference to a temporary copy in this case.

Putting the `std::ref()`, will cause the reference to the original to be used, and make the whole thing to work as expected.